# Is there a way to add a button in the unity editor like unity services?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

[image: unity services button]

I would want to make a button like this. Is there a way or is it just not possible?

I looked over the documentation but couldn't find what I was looking for. Just buttons for the inspector, menu items, and the tools overlay, but it's not what I'm looking for.
Maybe it is that I just don't know how to look for something on the internet, if that's the case sorry for the inconvenience.
And if you have an idea I would appreciate you share it.
Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not on a PC but this is the [source code of the Account Drop-down](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Modules/EditorToolbar/ToolbarElements/AccountDropdown.cs) you see the usage of [`EditorToolbarElementAttribute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Toolbars.EditorToolbarElementAttribute.html)

> ```
> [EditorToolbarElement("Services/Account", typeof(DefaultMainToolbar))]
> sealed class AccountDropdown : EditorToolbarDropdown
> {
>     ...
> ```

and then in your case inherit from [`EditorToolbarButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Toolbars.EditorToolbarButton.html) instead.

Also see the [source code of `DefaultMainToolbar`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/UIElements/DefaultMainToolbar.cs)

-> possible that it is not that easy to add additional items as seemingly there needs to be a spot reserved for the button - can't verify this right now

Also note that the type is internal so you don't have direct access to it! You need a bridge assembly .. e.g. naming your assembly `Unity.InternalAPIEditorBridge001`, this works because unity exposes their internal types accessible to assemblies with certain names

Comment: thank you very much, I'll try using this :)